# sending data around complex navigational stacks

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I would like some opinion, example and code on how everyone dose this..

So far I have been getting on fine using protocols and delegates for passing information back up through the navigaion controller from view to view.

However just recently I have had to pass some data across multiple views on the controller stack and just cannot figure out how to achive this with delegates and protocols.. I have asked some other question that have helped me under stand alot about what im trying to do but I want to come up with a application wide solution instead of several hashed together ideas that only just do what I need..

Basicly what I'm looking to do is is this

```
Navigation stack
- First View
-- second View
--- Third View - current view.
```

Pass data from Third to first view is the goal. I know how to pop to the first view controller.. I just don't know how to get information to it over that distance... The majour thing holding me back atm is that I cannot declare the delegate in the First View for the Third View delegate protocol with out the application falling over.

Comment: Have you considered using singletons?

Comment: I have looked at singletons... but I haven't looked in-depth into them... This is what I am planning now.. I need to find something thats going to suite my application design.. I thought protocols and delegates was going to do that for me but I was wrong.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how to do it if your delegate is defined in the Third View,

In your third view:

```
 YourFirstViewController *fvc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.delegate = fvc;
    [self.delegate yourMethodHere];
```

make sure your firstviewcontroller conforms to the protocol

```
<thirdViewDelegate>
```

and import third view in first view.h

Comment: okay going to do that after dinner.. it makes sense now.. hopefully I can get it working as I love my delegates.. lol
However I still think its going to be helpfull learning about the nsnotificatoncenter

Comment: This worked perfectly... sorry for the hassle of not understanding to begin with.. a few things went wrong my end with trying to solve it then endnig up with messy code.. but this worked perfectly after I resolved those issues.. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to use `observer pattern` with `NSNotificationCenter` class and `NSNotification` class. You can read the [apple official document here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701). That document page contains a `NSNotification Programming Topics` link inside. The data can be send to observers by a NSDictionary for userInfo.

With observer pattern, those view controller can be loose coupling. It is more flexible when changing original designs while developing project.

Comment: yes I have heard about this in another question I posted.. I'm going to do some reading on this now. Kinda seems alittle bit like java in respect to method listening for events etc. I'll keep this thread going to see if I get any other replies otherwise I'll mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the data on the device and accessing it separately. You could store all your data in an sqlite database and refresh the data when the view controller calls:

```
– viewWillAppear:
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the data that you like to pass back you can use a `Singleton, NSUserDefault, pass it via AppDelegate, use delegation pattern, or just use set of properties`. `The decision should be made by you according to the design and the requirement.` Assuming that you just wanna pass back a string you can do the below steps,

Declare a property in the FirstViewController.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *thePassbackValue;
```

Access the FirstViewController's instance in the ThirdView.

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Set the value to the property,

```
fvc.thePassbackValue = @"someValue";
```

Access the value back in the first view,

//In your first view,

```
if(self.thePassbackValue != nil)
{
//Use the value
NSLog(@"the value %@", self.thePassbackValue);
}
```